# Change unity sprite image through code and saving it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game character with sprite A. When I upgrade that character , I want to change the sprite to sprite B and save it, so that when I quit the game and start again, the character is now sprite B. Currently, I can change the sprite from A to B but when I quit and play again, it is showing sprite A instead of B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the sprites of your player into a Sprite list, sprite[0] for lv1 sprite, sprites[1] for lv2 sprite and so on. Then set your SpriteRenderer's sprite to the sprite in the list according to the saved level.

```
[SerializeField] List<Sprite> sprites;
[SerializeField] SpriteRenderer m_SpriteRenderer;
int currentLevel;

private void Start()
{
    currentLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PlayerLevel", 1); //load player level
    LoadCurrentSprite();
}

void LoadCurrentSprite()
{
    m_SpriteRenderer.sprite = sprites[currentLevel - 1];
}
```

When you change the character's level, call this

```
void SetPlayerLevel(int level)
{
    currentLevel = level;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlayerLevel", level);
    LoadCurrentSprite();
}
```